# SonataAdminBundle formMapper richtext

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

As title, could anybody help me the way to create a form with richtext content?

This is textarea for form but I dont know how to make it richtext editor:

```
$formMapper->add('settings', 'sonata_type_immutable_array', array(
        'keys' => array(
            array('content', 'textarea', array()),
        )
    ));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you should create your custom form type that would extend the `sonata_type_immutable_array` by specifying the "getParent" function as follow

```
public function getParent()
{
    return 'sonata_type_immutable_array';
}
```

From there, in the "setDafaults" method, you can do something like

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'richtext',
        )
    ));
}
```

Now, in your javascript that initializes your richtext editor, you can look for  your "richtext" class (with jQuery for example) and then initialize the editor.

For example with CKeditor :

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'richtext', {
    customConfig: ''
});
```

**AND IF** you don't know how to include Javascript files / libraries, you should consider having a look at [this part of the official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#including-stylesheets-and-javascripts-in-twig)

EDIT :

and **of course** use it with your formmapper directly as you would use any [custom form type.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html)